# pymongo mongodb: how to update the field of a record only if it already exists?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

suppose I have a mongo document as below that has two records:

```
[
    {"a": "a1", "b": "b1", "c": "c1", "d": "d1"},
    {"a": "a2", "b": "b2", "c": "c2", "d": "d2"}
]
```

and suppose I have a data dict as below:

```
{"c": "c3", "d": "d3", "e": "e3"}
```

I want to find one and update if the field already exists:

```
_collection.find_one_and_update(
            {"a": "a1", "b": "b1"},
            {"$set": data},
# SOME OPTIONS HERE?
        )
```

I want the result to be

```
[
    {"a": "a1", "b": "b1", "c": "c3", "d": "d3"},
    {"a": "a2", "b": "b2", "c": "c2", "d": "d2"}
]
```

not

```
[
    {"a": "a1", "b": "b1", "c": "c3", "d": "d3", "e", "e3"},
    {"a": "a2", "b": "b2", "c": "c2", "d": "d2"}
]
```

How should I do this? The point is that `data` is dynamic and might contain fields (key-value pairs) out of control.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Thanks to [@cmgchess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13583510/cmgchess)' comment, [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GI-DMclMm4z) is a cleaner implementation with update with aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "a": "a1",
  "b": "b1"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      merged: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            "c": "c3",
            "d": "d3",
            "e": "e3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      merged: {
        "$objectToArray": "$merged"
      },
      rootArray: {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      merged: {
        // filter the merge/update result if the key exists in original document
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$merged",
          "as": "m",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$m.k",
              "$rootArray.k"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$merged"
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

---

For a generic solution, you can first use `$mergeObjects` to perform an unconditional update of the payload you are giving and the `$$ROOT` document. Then use `$objectToArray` to convert the update result and `$$ROOT` document to arrays of k-v tuples. Perform a `$filter` on the update result with `$in` to see if the key is in the original document. Finally, use `$merge` to update the result back into the collection.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "a": "a1",
      "b": "b1"
    }
  },
  // compute the unconditional update/merge result first
  {
    $set: {
      merged: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            "c": "c3",
            "d": "d3",
            "e": "e3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      merged: {
        "$objectToArray": "$merged"
      },
      rootArray: {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      merged: {
        // filter the merge/update result if the key exists in original document
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$merged",
          "as": "m",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$m.k",
              "$rootArray.k"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$merged"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DZZe15SafzP)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/GI-DMclMm4z to match the update i guess